# C++ - Cannot link to Boost::logger using msys2 and cmake

Tags: c++, logging, boost, cmake

Building simple example from Boost:logger tutorial:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

My cmake file for this project:

```
# Adding Boost library
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

find_package(Boost 1.63.0
             COMPONENTS system
                        filesystem
                        log
                        unit_test_framework
             REQUIRED)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

# Adding main sources to build
file(GLOB PROJECT_SOURCES sources/*.cpp)
file(GLOB PROJECT_HEADERS sources/*.h)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
               ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
               ${PROJECT_HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

And I receive the next error message:

```
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   log
--   unit_test_framework
--   date_time
--   log_setup
--   thread
--   regex
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/path_to_build_folder/build
[ 10%] Linking CXX executable ProjectName.exe
C:/User/msys64/mingw64/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(default_sink.o):(.text$_ZN5boost16thread_exceptionC2EiPKc[_ZN5boost16thread_exceptionC2EiPKc]+0x14): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
C:/User/msys64/mingw64/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(exceptions.o):(.text+0x2601): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
C:/User/msys64/mingw64/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(exceptions.o):(.text+0x2732): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\ProjectName.dir\build.make:269: ProjectName.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/ProjectName.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:94: all] Error 2
```

As I understand, the error occurs because linker cannot link libboost_log to the boost system library. Is this correct? But system library should be included with the `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` as well.

How to fix this issue?

From Cmake file it can be seen that I use `filesystem` library for other stuff, and it compiled and worked normally. The issue occurs as only I include log library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you must also add the boost `thread` library.

---

Anyway, to avoid such problems, I would *strongly* recommend using the target syntax to link against boost.

I.e., instead of

```
find_package(Boost 1.63.0
             COMPONENTS system
                        filesystem
                        log
                        unit_test_framework
             REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
[...]
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

you can just use

```
find_package(Boost 1.63.0
             COMPONENTS log
             REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      Boost::log)
```

which automatically 1) set the required include directories, and 2) links to the dependencies of `Boost::log`.

Also, as a side remark, your `if(Boost_FOUND)` is unnecessary since CMake will fail if Boost is not found.

Comment: Adding `Boost::log` to `target_link_libraries` solved the issue. But with this solution it would be necessary to specify Boost library in two places, which is not good.

I checked `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` and library `libboost_system-mt.a` with `libboost_thread-mt.a` are presented there.

Comment: @Serbin What do you mean exactly with two places? I see only one. `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` shouldn't be necessary anymore.

Comment: We should specify Log library in `find_package` and in each `target_link_libraries`.